# rotate ads in a fixed sequence using php

Tags: php, refresh, sequence, shuffle

I am trying to add an ad position to a website. There are 2 ads which should rotate such that each time a user goes to that site, the ad alternates. I find that using shuffle will often times repeat the same ad. Is there a way to fix the rotation sequence?

My code:

```
<?php
$ad1="<a class='non-html' href='http://site1.com'><img src='ads/image1.jpg'</a>";
$ad2="<a class='non-html' href='http://site2.com'><img src='ads/image2.jpg'</a>";
$ads=array($ad1, $ad2);
shuffle($ads);
?>
<div class="ads">
<?php echo $ads[0]; ?>
</div> <!-- ads -->
```

Comment: You might like to consider using a cookie or session to remember which add you last showed this user

Comment: Here's a basic example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436854/print-each-item-of-array-in-order-one-per-page-refresh